# Column Overriding issue in inheritance Sqlalchemy ORM

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
here are the three table for more context of what i have and what i want to achieve

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50))
     __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user'
    }
class Admin(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'admin'
    }
class SSP(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'ssp',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }
```

#### now i want to add another common field in User which is email, but the interesting part is i want to use email as nullable=True for Admin but nullable=False for SSP but i want to keep that field in User table instead of using separately in both tables,

#### because i want to override it only in one table so goes like this

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(50))
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique= True, nullable=False)
     __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_on': type,
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user'
    }
class Admin(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    state = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'admin'
    }
class SSP(User):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique= True, nullable=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'ssp',
        'inherit_condition': id == User.id
    }
```

#### when i try like this then i get a warning that, how can i bypass this warning and achieve my goal, Thanks

```
SAWarning: Implicitly combining column user.email with column ssp.email under attribute 'email'.  Please configure one or more attributes for these same-named columns explicitly.
  super().__init__(name, bases, d, **kwargs)
```